# Latex listings package: How to define comments not by delimiters but by their position

Tags: latex, listings, gams-math

I am using the [listings package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) for LaTex to include GAMS-Code in my LaTex-file. The package does not support GAMS as a language. So I have to define the language like descriped in [this article](http://blog.modelworks.ch/gams-code-in-latex-documents/).
In GAMS, after declaring a symbol there is place for an explanatory text. I want to make the listings package to recognize this as a comment, so I can set special color options and keywords are not formated as keywords. But I can only define comments by their delimiters and not by their position (starting the second word after certain keywords).
So as an example the GAMS code contains

```
sets i decision variables
```

Then "decision variables" is the explanatory text and I want it to have a different color (blue). "variables" is a keyword but it should not be marked as one in my Latex-file because it is inside the explanatory text. Is there any chance of making the listings package recognizing the explanatory text as a comment. What would my LaTex command

```
\lstdefinelanguage{GAMS}{
    morekeywords={sets, variables,...}
    morecomment= <This should be the interesting part>
```

look like?

Comment: GAMS allows to put quotes (single and/or double quotes) around this explanatory text, so your example could look like this:

    Sets i "Decision variables";

Maybe you could always use that for the explanatory text and thus use the " as an additional comment character in LaTex?

Comment: Seems like a good workaround. Thank you @Lutz, I will use that.